# Why does SQLAlchemy start a transaction with SELECT

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The following code raises the error `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: A transaction is already begun on this Session` when it gets to the line `with session.begin():`

```
import datetime
from sqlalchemy                 import create_engine, select, Integer, Column, String, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm             import Session
Base = declarative_base()

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = "people"
    id            = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    name          = Column(String(128), nullable = False)
    created_at    = Column(DateTime, nullable = False,
                           default=datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc))
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #                                                                                             
dsn     = 'sqlite:////tmp/people.sqlite'
engine  = create_engine(dsn, echo=True)
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = Session(engine, future=True)

p = Person(name="Able")
session.add(p)
session.commit()

print("About to do a select...")
sel = select(Person).filter_by(name="Able")
q = session.execute(sel).scalars().first()
print(q.created_at)

with session.begin():
    print("hello")
```

Looking at the verbose output I can see that SQLAlchemy starts a transaction when executing the SELECT. I can see why it would start a transaction with an INSERT or UPDATE, but why does it start a transaction with a SELECT?

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_basics.html? As it does not look like you follow the recommended approach.

Comment: See the "Discussion" section of [this topic](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_20.html#library-level-but-not-driver-level-autocommit-removed-from-both-core-and-orm) in the 2.0 migration guide.